# Vue-snotify, mudar posição da função async

Tags: html, vue.js

Tem um plugin de notificações toast chamado Vue-snotify [Vue-Snotify](https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/documentation/essentials/examples.html#async)

Tem uma função que faz uma requisição com axios, e antes de completar a requisição mostra uma notificação de loading, e depois uma do resultado de sucesso ou erro.
Porém ela fica na posição bottonRight, eu queria mudar essa posição, não achei em lugar algum.

```
 this.$snotify.async('Called with promise', 'Success async', () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({
    title: 'Success!!!',
    body: 'We got an example success!',
    config: {
      closeOnClick: true
    }
  }), 2000);
}));
```

Comment: Basta olha na documentação: https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/documentation/api/enums.html#snotifyposition tem várias opções

Comment: Vlw André, deu certo